# How to create / update a connections blog post using the IBM SBT SDK java API

Tags: java, blogs, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

At the moment, I am trying to create and update blog posts using the java sbt sdk api.

I could read blogs and blog posts and was able to retrieve a single blog post, using the .getBlogPost(bkogHandle, postId) method of the SDK.

But if I try to update or create a blog post, either I run into a NullPointerException or nothing happens.

For testing purposes I created a demo blog and tried to update the blog post inside it:

```
String blogHandle = "citb";
String postId = "7973d29e-26b6-4d23-ab04-ebfb734bf512";
BlogPost post = sbcs.getBlogService().getBlogPost(blogHandle, postId);

if (null != post){
    System.out.println("Found post "+post.getTitle()+" ("+post.getAlternateUrl()+")");
    Map<String, Object> fieldMap = post.getFieldsMap();
    System.out.println("Found "+fieldMap.keySet().size()+" Entries in the field Map");

    try{    
    //Save the post
        System.out.println("Update blog post");
        post.setContent("<p dir='ltr'>blabla "+new Date()+"</p>");
        System.out.println(post.getContent());
        post.setTitle(post.getTitle()+" +");
        sbcs.getBlogService().updateBlogPost(post, blogHandle);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This example runs without throwing an exception but doesn't update the blog. 
Do I miss something?

If I use `post.save(blogHandle);` I get the this error messages:

```
com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.blogs.BlogServiceException: error creating blog post
at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.blogs.BlogService.createBlogPost(BlogService.java:627)
at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.blogs.BlogPost.save(BlogPost.java:128)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.blogs.feedhandler.BlogsFeedHandler.createEntity(BlogsFeedHandler.java:42)
at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.blogs.BlogService.createBlogPost(BlogService.java:624)
... 2 more
```

I get the same errors if I use `createBlogPost(post, blogHandle)`to create a new post.

Any ideas what the problem is or any suggestions what I could do to save blog posts?

EDIT:

In the BlogService class the problem seems to be in the following method

```
public BlogPost createBlogPost(BlogPost post, String blogHandle) throws BlogServiceException {
        if (null == post){
            throw new BlogServiceException(null,"null post");
        }
        Response result = null;
        try {
            BaseBlogTransformer transformer = new BaseBlogTransformer(post);
            Object  payload = transformer.transform(post.getFieldsMap());

            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/atom+xml");
            String createPostUrl = resolveUrl(blogHandle, FilterType.CREATE_BLOG_POST, null);
            **result = createData(createPostUrl, null, headers, payload);**
            **post = (BlogPost) new BlogPostsFeedHandler(this).createEntity(result);**

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BlogServiceException(e, "error creating blog post");
        }
        return post;
    }
```

Comment: curious, what version of the SDK do you have?

Comment: I use sbtsdk-1.0.0.20131101-1513. Should be the newest release, or am I mistaken?

Comment: In the IBM Connections wiki, the REST API documentation (http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.5+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Retrieving_the_Blogs_service_document_ic45&content=pdcontent) says, that I need to get the service document, but I think, the SDK does that for me, right? At least, I couldn't find any such requirements (or methods) in the javadoc

Comment: I added the method of the BlogService class which throws the error in the question above, for better reference

Comment: it's always good to check, that's right the SDK developers have already done this for you.   I asked a colleague to look at

Comment: Ah,  as I just found out, the save method of the BlogPost class also just calls the createBlogPost method of the BlogService

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce this issue but I fixed a bug on updateBlogPost just few days back , I don't think it is available in the mentioned build. So we'll have to check when the next build is due and we can confirm if the issue still comes.

for the save() in BlogPost -I'll make changes in it so as to return the updated BlogPost

Comment: Thank you for your response. When is the next build scheduled to be published?

Comment: we are expecting a release by end of this week or early next week, but meanwhile can you try running the "updateBlogPost" sample present under blogs Java samples category and let me know if you see the same issue there

Comment: Sorry, but which "updateBlogPost" sample do you mean. Where should I search?

Comment: The one in the "sbt.sample.web", if I start the tomcat server shipped with the SDK?

Comment: com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.blogs.BlogServiceException: error creating blog post  
at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.blogs.BlogService.createBlogPost(BlogService.java:627)  
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException  
at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.blogs.feedhandler.BlogsFeedHandler.createEntity(BlogsFeedHandler.java:42)  
at com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.blogs.BlogService.createBlogPost(BlogService.java:624)  
... 2 more

Comment: Ok, now I tried updateBlogPost. No exception but no result either, in the first run. I checked the configuration again and found that there was a problem with the proper authentication. After fixing that, updateBlogPost worked. But shouldn't there be a message stating that authentication is missing instead of just doing... nothing?

Comment: for the CreateBlogPost, I think i understand the issue , it is currently getting public blogs and trying to create a post in one of the blog , and if the user is not a owner of the blog it throws exception. I've fixed it .for the other point, I agree that java samples should show more meaningful messages in conveying what exactly what went wrong. what was the problem with authentication.. in case you used default endpoint i.e connections endpoint with basic authentication, it shows login page and wrong crendetials message if wrong credentials were provided

Comment: Since I am calling the method inside a java app / notes rcp plugin job no login page is shown (can be shown). So I had no real clue what went wrong until double checking the authentication. I am thinking about, what could be done, to help in such cases... perhaps provide an error list in the service class, which can be queried for the last problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the exact cause for failure from service specific exception class, in this case BlogServiceException. BlogServiceException encapsulates all exceptions which might have been caused while communicating with Connections including Authentication and Authorization ones.

Another alternative for debugging and seeing all network calls would be redirect all traffic to debugging utility like fiddler, details for setting up SBT with fiddler can be fetched from this link [SBT Wiki](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Social%20Business%20Toolkit%20SDK%20documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Debugging_network_traffic_in_SDK_SDK1.0&content=pdcontent)